# Wiring a new bathroom fan

Tags: electrical, bathroom

I'm installing a new ventilation fan in the bathroom but the existing electrical is coming out of metal conduit in the wrong location. The old fan had the ground wire cut so I'm assuming it's using the conduit as ground.  What's the best way to extend this to the right location? I was considering flexible conduit but that would require a junction box and this is a really tight place in the attic I can't get to from above.

[image]

Comment: What is the distance it needs to be moved?  There should be different connectors or might just need to bend it a bit.

Comment: It needs to go in the top left corner. I can swing it in an arc but no where close to where it needs to be, its off by several inches

Comment: Could I cut the existing conduit and connect flexible conduit in it's place?